# Marionette module not firing 'start' event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have create a marionette module like this

```
App.module("HeaderApp", function (HeaderApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    HeaderApp.on('start', function () {
        ...do something....
    });
});
```

When I call `App.module("HeaderApp").start()` the event listener does not fire, however if I manually trigger the event it will run.

Reading the [marionette documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#start-events) it seems as though this should work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely, it's because the module auto-starts with the app and is therefore already running by the time you register the event listener.

To prevent auto start, set `startWithParent` to false (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#preventing-auto-start-of-modules) :

```
App.module("HeaderApp", function (HeaderApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    HeaderApp.startWithParent = false;

    HeaderApp.on('start', function () {
        ...do something....
    });
});
```

Then it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David! It very coincidental that you are giving me help, as I am actually using your book marionette - "a gentle introduction" as a reference, loving it!